# Как показать все четырехбуквенные слова в порядке убывания частоты?

Tags: python, nltk

Я пытаюсь понять наилучшие способы фильтрации и сортировки текста в соответствии с их длиной и распределенной частотой.

> Find all the four-letter words in the Chat Corpus (text5). With the help of a frequency distribution (FreqDist), show these words in decreasing order of frequency.
>
> *Natural Language Processing with Python*, [Ch1](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html) from Steven Bird, Ewan Klein and Edward Loper

То есть, Найдите все четырехбуквенные слова в Chat Corpus (текст5). С помощью частотного распределения (FreqDist) покажите эти слова в порядке убывания частоты.

Я попробовал это. Я думаю, что это показывает его в порядке убывания частоты, но я не уверен, что это самый эффективный способ, поскольку я должен писать его на трех строках.

```
>>> from nltk.books import *
>>> aux = sorted(w for w in set(text2) if len(w) == 4)
>>> aux.reverse()
>>> aux
[u'zeal', u'your', u'year', u'yard'...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from nltk import FreqDist

freq = FreqDist(w for w in text5 if len(w) == 4)

res = [w for w,no in freq.most_common()]
```

Пример работы метода `FreqDist.most_common()`:

```
In [17]: freq.most_common(10)
Out[17]:
[('JOIN', 1021),
 ('PART', 1016),
 ('that', 274),
 ('what', 183),
 ('here', 181),
 ('....', 170),
 ('have', 164),
 ('like', 156),
 ('with', 152),
 ('chat', 142)]
```